# Getting my plot image to look the same between the r plot window and r markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am new to using R Markdown and am trying to get my plots on the output to look the same as the plot that shows in the plot window of RStudio. Below is the code I have been using for the R Markdown page:

````
```{r rawplot, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, fig.width=7.65, fig.height=5.88}
sept13 <- ggplot(sept_13, aes(x=transactiondate, y=amount))
sept13 + geom_line(aes(color=type, group=type)) + 
   labs(title="Daily Payment Amounts in Sept 2013", x="Date", y="Amount Paid")
```
````

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFISC.png) is the image it will produce on the output page. 
However, that is not how I would like it to look. When the plot is generated in RStudio the plot window produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ask2E.png) image. I have fiddled around with the fig.width and fig.height options in R Markdown but I just can't get it to look right. Is there something I'm forgetting or is there a way to get the plot to 'autofit' the output page? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you use the button in RStudio, then your code is run in an isolated R session and doesn't have access to the global environment. Try restarting your R session and running **only** the code in your code chunks, and you will be able to debug the rmarkdown results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the data is quite different in those two plots. I suspect you are not really given them the same data, that is an easy mistake to make since you have to maintain two different sources. I have had exactly this problem several times in the past.

Try listing the data behind the plots in both cases (you can do that in markdown as well) and examine them closely.

If they are the same then augment your question with both of those listings.